# Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew - PR to fix it?

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

brew upgrade:

```
Warning: Calling plist_options is deprecated! Use service.require_root instead.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb:55
```

brew doctor:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: No Cask quarantine support available: unknown reason.
Warning: Calling plist_options is deprecated! Use service.require_root instead.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb:55
```

mongodb-community:

```
brew list mongodb-community
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/bin/install_compass
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/bin/mongod
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/bin/mongos
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/MPL-2
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.4/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

What causes this 'report'? Does it need "a PR to fix it"?

Comment: I have created a ticket for mongo team to check on the issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-74134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has now been fixed in the Mongo's homebrew package.

See following pull requests:

https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/pull/176

and

https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/pull/174